# Why does readymade food always have so much flavor to it?

Tags: flavor

What am I doing wrong. When I make food it's never as flavorful however much seasonings I use.

Comment: If the goal is to make your food more flavorful, this question has a lot of good tips: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/why-do-things-smell-good-while-cooking-but-have-little-flavour-when-finished?rq=1

Comment: Your question is too vague. What seasonings are you adding? Why are you adding them? To what kind of food? Too much of any one of them can overwhelm what you are doing.

Comment: fat, salt, sugar, and miscellaneous chemicals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readymade foods use [flavour enhancers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_enhancer), artificial flavours and other additives that improve the [mouthfeel](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthfeel&ei=qmKlUMrAN6WRiQeuh4HYBg&usg=AFQjCNFQBniPVGrY54qO9EZR8Skz2y2sOg&sig2=rBFTVVH5zuuyykXbYZuqUQ) and appearance of their product. Most ingredients lose much of their appeal during industrial processing so this kind of trickery is necessary.

Undoubtedly you can make food that tastes *much* better than readymade. There really is no substitute for freshly made food made from in-season fruit and vegetables. It's difficult to give general advice on how to do this. There is a great deal to learn before you can cook flavourful food consistently. I have been serious about cooking for about four years now and my cooking, if I'm to be honest, is still a bit hit-and-miss.

I suggest you start with some good, dependable recipes. The recipes on the [America's Test Kitchen](http://www.americastestkitchen.com/) site are developed with simplicity in mind and don't compromise too much on flavour. I started cooking with a recipe book from [Heston Blumenthal](http://amzn.com/0747584095) which was technically challenging but also a great way to learn a lot about cooking in a short space of time. There are more cookbook ideas in [this (closed) question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-cookbooks-do-you-always-come-back-to).

Try a recipe. If it doesn't turn out as you had hoped, do some research and try again. If you are still having trouble you can always come back here for more specific advice.

Comment: False dichotomy, I'd say - some of these "flavour enhancers" aren't that artificial, and will also enhance a home cooked dish.