# Ways for success on cast iron crepe pans without cooking spray

Tags: cast-iron, crepe

I get good results making crepes on non-stick pans.

[image: making crepes on non-stick pans]

It's quite easy to flip a crepe, but it's hard to get the surface to be golden. The color remains closer to white, as you see in the picture above.

On ceramic-enameled cast iron, I can get the heat considerably higher, but crepes will stick.

[image: making crepes on enameled cast iron pans]

I see on the market cast iron pans marketed specifically for crepes, and I'm wondering whether the polymer cover from a good seasoning makes it easier to prepare a batch of crepes.

Is there a way to avoid cooking spray when preparing crepes on a cast iron pan? One reason for my failure on enameled cookware (I'm guessing) is that it's hard to add fat to the pan. Here I'd like to avoid using cooking sprays with a multitude of ingredients. I'd like to use butter only. Adding butter on the hot pan will brown (burn) the butter too quickly. Hence it's necessary to remove the pan, cool off for a few seconds, add the butter, then return to heat, which makes the process too time consuming. And even then, the butter is not a uniform coat. Using a brush, whether made from hair or from silicone, is a way to melt the brush.

The batter already has fat (butter). On non-stick, no additional fat is needed. On either of the other two, it's necessary.

Asked another way, what is the secret of making crepes on a (well-seasoned) cast iron pan?

**Related**:

- Does cast iron enable making crepes with [no additional fat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/45940/85398) (besides that in the batter)? (that would be nice!)
- Is the [Leidenfrost point](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/12292/85398) relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enameled cast iron is indeed not as good as non-enameled, because you can't heat it as much. But it still should give you good crepes. If your butter burns, just use simple oil instead of butter - any oil will do, the more refined, the better (so the cheapest no-plant-named ones work best). It may burn to the point of getting dark brown, but you won't get the tiny coal particles you get when butter solids burn.

> I'd like to use butter only.

> it's hard to get the surface to be golden

These two wishes are mutually exclusive. No matter what pan material you are using, if you get the proper heat transfer rate for getting a golden crepe, butter will burn badly.

Comment: Ah! That clarifies a lot. But how do you apply a uniform layer of (corn, sunflower) oil? What is the trick to spreading it uniformly, short of spraying it?

Comment: As a quick sequel to your _other_ answer (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/45940/85398), is it possible to make crepes with **no** additional fat at all on a well-seasoned (crepe) cast iron pan, besides that in the batter? I am willing to experiment with temperature until I find the narrow window where that is doable, but I'd like to know whether this can be done in the first place.

Comment: You pour a thick layer of oil into a very hot pan, then pour most of it back out into a cup. Only a few droplets and rivulets remain on the pan, but they are sufficient. As for no additional fat, not entirely. If you have a nonenameled (home-seasoned) cast iron, you can keep back the oiling and only put in oil once per 2-3 crepes. But afterwards, the next crepe will stick for me. I don't know for sure if that's due to temperature control or if you need a minimal amount of oil remaining. I have never cared for oil in the batter, doesn't seem to stop sticking for me.

Comment: One option you have to use butter without having the burnt butter solids is to use clarified butter or ghee; that way you should retain a good deal of the butter flavour while still being able to bring it up to the temperatures you need.

Comment: I wouldn't say any oil will do, olive oil will smoke at a relatively low temperature.

Comment: @GdD all oils will be above smoke point at the right temperature for nice golden crepes. There is a slight advantage in getting one that has a higher smoke point, that's why I said "the more refined, the better" - but the difference between an extra virgin olive oil and an aggressively refined sunflower oil will be a difference in the degree of smoking, not a "this one works, this dosn't". None of them will have solids that will burn the way butter solids do.